# Reference an external URL for swagger-UI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm working on a project with Spring boot and we already have a swagger documentation for it as a json file. We just included Swagger-ui and it's rendered under /projectName/swagger-ui.html.

We would like to make use of the external URL that references our Swagger json which is /projectName/docs/swagger.

How can we achieve such behavior on Swagger-UI to make use of our own URL and not the /v2/docs default.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside *projectName/docs/swagger* there must be a index.yaml if i am not wrong. Add host for external call there.

```
host: '(your ip address):(port number)'
```

like

```
host: '127.0.0.1:8080'
```

Then enable your API CORS for this request.

Comment: Good answer but I found out a new way to achieve what I wanted using the new Swagger UI v3 from their Github. Thank you